# NodeJs + NickJs: Make synchronous call in asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous

I'm using NickJs to make WebRequests. For the most part, NickJs does what I need (open browser, navigate, etc). However I need to make a synchronous call (a custom WebRequest) to another service before continuing on in my code execution.

I can not figure out how to correctly make this call synchronous. My current setup uses NickJs which is wrapped in an async function and uses 'await' to wait for the WebRequest to return.

I don't think I can use this for my custom request but I feel like I should be able to make my own function and wait for the WebRequest to complete before moving on in code execution.

Example:

```
const nick = new Nick({
  printNavigation: false,
  printResourceErrors: true,
  printPageErrors: true,
  resourceTimeout: 10000,
  userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36",
})

    ; (async () => {

    await tab.open("https://google.com")

    //custom function here to request another webpage from another service
    //and wait for the result before moving on to next await call

    //Continue on as normal with code
    await tab.open("https://google.com")

    })()
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Hooray!")
      nick.exit()
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(`Boo!: ${err}`)
      nick.exit(1)
    })
```

Comment: You can't make an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one.  Can't be done in Javascript.  `await` gives you some "synchronous-like" programming within the function its in, but even then it's not entirely synchronous and the containing function will be `async` and return a promise.  It will not be synchronous or blocking.

Comment: So, rather than ask how to do something that can't be done, why don't you change your question into a programming problem statement.  How do I write code X to accomplish Y?

Comment: Okay, how do I write the above code to make a WebRequest that will wait for a response before continuing execution?

Comment: I ended up solving this using 'deasync' and wrapping the call in a sleep function. Not ideal, but it worked...

Comment: It sounds like you just need to learn how one structures asynchronous operations in node.js.  You don't just make a function call and expect it to synchronously execute your operation and not return until it does.  node.js just doesn't work that way.  Instead, you return a promise from the operation and any code that follows that function call that you don't want to be executed until that prior asynchronous operation is done you put INSIDE the `.then()` handle on that promise.  That's how you  structure sequential async operations in node.js.  I'd suggest you learn how to do that.